# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, cascade, many-to-one

I have ManyToOne relation: Many Sessions to One Hall.

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
public class Session {

    //...some params

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "hall_id")
    private Hall hall;
}


@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
public class Hall {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;
}
```

I want to delete sessions by doing next:
iterate through all sessions, clear some data, than set Hall to null - which is used as foreign key.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void clearSessions(List<Session> sessions) {
        sessions.forEach(s -> {
            s.getSessionViewers().clear();
            s.getMessages().clear();
            s.setHall(null);
            sessionRepository.delete(s);// Error here <---
        });
    }
```

But steel have an error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`session`, CONSTRAINT `FK14qoadsfdvgkbld832ddaDDk` FOREIGN KEY (`hall_id`) REFERENCES `hall` (`id`))

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are making changes to the session before deleting it. Shouldn't you save the changes before doing the delete?

Comment: don't do `s.setHall(null);` that.